# How to create an animated AVIF from images

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I have 6 images in .avif format I want to encode to a a single animated avif file.

I could create a .gif from images easily with ffmpeg and convert the generated .gif to .avif But I still want a more direct method

I've tried the following but it only reencodes the .avif images one by one without making a single animated AVIF file

```bash
ffmpeg -i *.avif -f yuv4mpegpipe -strict -1 - | avifenc --stdin --fps 13 output.avif
```

and with:

```bash
$ ffmpeg  -pattern_type glob -i '*.avif' -strict -1 -pix_fmt yuv420p10 -f yuv4mpegpipe - | avifenc --stdin --fps 13 output.avif
$ ffmpeg -f image2pipe -r 13 -pattern_type glob -i '*.avif' - | avifenc --stdin output.avif
$ ffmpeg -framerate 1/interval -i '*.avif' -vf "fps=1/interval" -pix_fmt yuv420p -f yuv4mpegpipe - | avifenc --stdin -o output.avif
```

With the above 3 commands I receive an error:

```bash
*.avif: No such file or directory
​[1]    901919 exit 1                            ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i '*.avif' -strict -1 -pix_fmt yuv420p10 -f  - | 
       901920 segmentation fault (core dumped)  avifenc --stdin --fps 13 output.avif
```

I've got a linux up to date system with ffmpeg 6.0

Answer (score 0):

First create a list with each image and the duration you want it to be displayed, something like:

```
file '01.avif'
duration 3
file '02.avif'
duration 3
file '03.avif'
duration 3
```

Next usa a command like this:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -vf "format=yuv420p,scale=800:-1" -an -loop 0 -c:v libaom-av1 out.avif
```

Comment: Why can't it be `-i '*.avif'`? or framerate flag: `ffmpeg -framerate 2 -i 01.avif -i 02.avif _rest_of_the_command`. 
Ideally, a perfect way would be `ffmpeg -framerate 2 -i '*.avif* _rest_of_the_command`.

Comment: Could probably work too, have you tried it without piping (|) ?

Comment: I've tried your suggested command and only made the changes I just mentioned.
When I do: `ffmpeg -framerate 2 -i *.avif -vf "format=yuv420p,scale=800:-1" -an -loop 0 -c:v libaom-av1 out.avif`ffmpeg complain about: `Option framerate not found.`. 
And if I change `*.avif` for `'*.avif'`ffmpeg complains about: `*.avif: No such file or directory.`

Comment: try with -pattern_type glob

Comment: Same deal as previous comment. Though, your answer was okay, I do still prefer to use globbing for making an animated AVIF, It's more practical that way.

Comment: Do the images have sequenced names like 01.avif 02.avif 03.avif?

Comment: Tried renaming the filenames like that, but no, no luck.

Comment: One moment I'm going to edit the answer....

Comment: I've just tested, and found out that jpg and png can be succefully _transcoded_? is the word? to an animated avif file. I still don't know why the globbing do not work with avif images though.

Comment: Seems you are right, with the concat options it seems to work to convert still avif images to an animated avif file but if you try it with globbing or sequenced images it doesn't seem to work except if the images are jpg, png or something that is not avif....

Comment: There must be something we are missing...

Comment: This may have something to do with it, when I look at the output while using the concat filter this is show in the output screen: (av1 (libdav1d) -> av1 (libaom-av1)) it looks like still images are encoded with libdav1d while animated avif files are encoded with libaom-av1...

Comment: That's normal. `(av1 (libdav1d)` is just the Type Format being used and `av1 (libaom-av1))` the container. Maybe ffmpeg has yet to fully support AVIF in this regard. Or we're simply missing something.